# my static files like images are not displayed after deploying my django 2.2 app

Tags: python, django, ovh

when I deploy my django 2.2 app on OVH but the static files like the image is not displayed even though the path is correct

myapp/settings

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'layout/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <img src="{% static 'images/fondu2.png' %}" style="width:500px;height:500px">
   
{% endblock content %}
```

myapp/urls.py

```
.......
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
]
```

where is the problem?

Comment: What is OVH? Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Django doesn't serve static files in production, so if you don't have separate configuration to serve your static files (NGINX / Apache or some other web server) then this would be expected.

Comment: OVH is a web host that I use,
And STATIC_ROOT I have to define what there